# Why do we need to concatenate the positional vectors when sub setting from a simple uni dimensional vector?

Tags: r, subset

Consider the following line:

```
y <- list(foo=1:4, bar=0.6, baz="hello")

y[1,3]
# Error in y[1, 3] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I understand that the correct way to do this is to call out the positions by `y[c(1,3)]`. But why do we do that?

Comment: You'll want to read the help pages for `extract` or `[`

Comment: Counter-question: Why would we do it your way? That would be very confusing.

Comment: Help page is [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html). Short answer is that a list only has an `i` dimension and R interprets `y[1,3]` as trying to index the 1st element from `i` and third element from `j`. Since there's no `j`, you get an error. In contrast, `y[c(1,3)]` is interpreted as "give me the first and third elements from `i`.

Comment: @Chase might as well just post as answer.

Comment: Basically, same reason that `mean(1, 2, 3)` is `1`, but `mean(c(1, 2, 3))` is `2`. Positions of arguments are important. `[` is defined so that subsequent unnamed argument correspond to dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

With `y[1,3]` you reference row index 1 and column index 3 of a two-dimensional object, e. g. a two-dimensional matrix.

With `y[c(1,3)]` applied to a list, you reference list contents at index 1 and index 3, so this reference is one-dimensional.